# Detect specific change during Eloquent Updated event

Tags: laravel

Using Eloquent Events/Observers, is it possible to detect which properties were updated within an Update event? Or, can you gain access to the previous/new values to do a comparison?

I'm finding the only solution is to manually fire events by detecting the specific field exists in the validated request data, in the controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  You can use the Model class's existing methods to gain access to various sets of data.  The following methods should be helpful for what you want to do.

**[getChanges()](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getChanges)**
Get the attributes that were changed. *(and saved)*

```php
$model->getChanges()
```

**[getOriginal()](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getOriginal)**
Get the model's original attribute values.

```php
$model->getOriginal()
```

**[getDirty()](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getDirty)**
Get the attributes that have been changed since last sync. *(but not saved yet)*

```php
$model->getDirty()
```

Comment: I love it when it's this simple and lovely. Working brilliantly, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure!  I have updated the explanations to better indicate the difference between `getChanges()` and `getDirty()` as my initial recollection was not quite correct.

Comment: Whilst this is the right answer, the following package is handy too https://github.com/envant/fireable

Comment: Three years later - I now do it the stock Laravel way, as provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

```
    static::updated(function (User $user) {
        if ($user->wasChanged('title')) {
            // Title was changed and saved to DB
        }
        if ($user->isDirty('title')) {
            // Title was changed
        }
    });
```

[Examining Attribute Changes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes)